# Android Jetpack compose gradient

Tags: android, gradient, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to draw a gradient over an image drawable using Jetpack Compose?

```
fun HeroCover() {
    Column {
        val image = +imageResource(R.drawable.edge_of_tomorrow_poster)
        Container(modifier = Height(440.dp) wraps Expanded) {
            Clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) {
                DrawImage(image = image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have a translucent gradient drawn on top of the image.

Comment: Could you please provide an image of the required output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65697832/14004870 Refer this answer I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
                )
            )
        )
) {
    Content()
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue and complies with Compose latest API changes after BETA

Comment: Perfect code in jetpack compose!

Comment: Does this not draw Content _on top_ of gradient?

Comment: @jayeffkay yes! the Content function should draw anything you need and the gradient will be the background.

Comment: Thanks @LuisFerGarcia, this answer helped me. But it doesn't put the gradient on top of the image as per OP's question. Given the image is drawn in content.

Answer (score 17):

Here is an example of how a LinearGradientShader is used in Compose on a paint object. I imagine you could use something similar to get what you want

https://gist.github.com/lelandrichardson/35b2743e1acd5d672f963f92aca57d4a#file-shimmer-kt-L83

**Update**: Here's another way to do it that I stumbled on in kotlin lang slack channels -

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .preferredSize(500.dp, 500.dp)
        .drawBackground(
            HorizontalGradient(
                0.0f to Color.Red,
                0.5f to Color.Green,
                1.0f to Color.Blue,
                startX = Px.Zero,
                endX = 500.dp.toPx()
            )
        )
)
```

Source: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1590430288092800

Comment: I cannot find toPx() function

Comment: for `toPx()` method, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65921800/75579

Comment: Outdated, the answer from Luis is simpler and just working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way inspired from the Jetsnack sample code:
Replace transparent & darkChocolate by your own colors.

```
@Composable
fun GradientView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.verticalGradientBackground(listOf(transparent, darkChocolate)))
}

fun Modifier.verticalGradientBackground(
        colors: List<Color>
) = drawWithCache {
    val gradient = VerticalGradient(startY = 0.0f, endY = size.width, colors = colors)
    onDraw {
        drawRect(brush = gradient)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
  @Composable
  fun GradientBackground() {
    val gradientBrush = Brush.verticalGradient(
        colors = listOf(Color.Blue, Color.Red), // Gradient colors
        startY = 0f, // Starting Y position of the gradient
        endY = 500f // Ending Y position of the gradient
    )

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(brush = gradientBrush),
        text = "Hello, Gradient Text",
        color = Color.White
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this extension and enjoy!

first create Class in your *core* or *util* presentation layer
just copy it, u don't need to change it :)

```
@Composable
fun VerticalGradient(
    modifier: Modifier,
    listColors: List<Color>,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listColors
                )
            ),
        content = content
    )
}
```

and then, just use it! It's that simple.

to use it, just do this:

```
VerticalGradient(
        modifier = Modifier,
        // Change Colors, you can add TWO or more Colors
        listColors = listOf(Color.White, Color.DarkGray, Color.Black)
    ) {
        // Your Code Must be HERE
        Text(text="Dummy Text", color = Color.White)
    }
```