# Gradient over image in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, gradient, android-jetpack-compose

Here is my component:

```
@Composable
fun Cover(
    name: String,
    imageRes: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp, 8.dp)
) {
    Box(modifier) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            elevation = 4.dp
        ) {
            Stack {
                Image(
                    imageResource(imageRes),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .gravity(Alignment.Center)
                        .aspectRatio(2f),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                )

                Text(
                    text = name,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .gravity(Alignment.BottomStart)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: cover]

I want to display a dark gradient over the `Image` and behind the `Text` so that the text is easy to read. I guess I'll have to use `LinearGradient` or `RadialGradient` but due to the lack of documentation I'm not able to do it.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991395/add-gradient-to-imageview) is what I'm trying to do but with Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Use `Modifier.drawBackground()` to pass `LinearGradient` or `RadialGradient`

Comment: @MohammadSianaki the function is now called just Modifier.background()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Compose version `1.2.1` as of `2022-08-22`

```kotlin
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun Cover(
    name: String,
    @DrawableRes imageRes: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(modifier.padding(16.dp, 8.dp)) {
        Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)) {
            Box {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(imageRes),
                    contentDescription = "image: $name",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.Center),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
                Text(
                    text = name,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(
                            Brush.verticalGradient(
                                0F to Color.Transparent,
                                .5F to Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5F),
                                1F to Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8F)
                            )
                        )
                        .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp, top = 24.dp),
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ComicsPreview() {
    Cover(
        "Comics",
        R.drawable.comics
    )
}
```

The updated answer of [@vitor-ramos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8894262/vitor-ramos)

### `1.0.0-alpha09`

```kotlin
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onGloballyPositioned
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.AmbientDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.res.imageResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import tech.abd3lraouf.learn.compose.kombose.ui.theme.typography

@Composable
fun Cover(
    name: String,
    @DrawableRes imageRes: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val image = imageResource(imageRes)
    val density = AmbientDensity.current.density
    val width = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val height = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Box(
        modifier
            .padding(16.dp, 8.dp)
    ) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            elevation = 4.dp
        ) {
            Box {
                Image(
                    image,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .aspectRatio(2f)
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            width.value = it.size.width / density
                            height.value = it.size.height / density
                        },
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                )
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .size(width.value.dp, height.value.dp)
                        .background(
                            Brush.verticalGradient(
                                listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black),
                                image.height * 0.6F,
                                image.height * 1F
                            )
                        )
                ) {}
                Text(
                    text = name,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    style = typography.body2,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, notice the control of how the gradient draws its height.

### The output

[image: Code output]

Comment: it seems AmbientDensity has been removed from Compose, I couldn't find any explanation for it anyhow, can you please give some explanation of how it works? what it is and what is been replaced with? Also is it possible to keep Modifier inside the remember and change the background value of main Container on click of a button?

Comment: Hi @ArashAfsharpour val density = AmbientDensity.current.density you can use val density = LocalDensity.current.density instead. It worked for me, hope it works for you :)

Comment: nice it helped me ! thanks

Answer (score 33):

You can use something like:

```
var sizeImage by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

val gradient = Brush.verticalGradient(
    colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black),
    startY = sizeImage.height.toFloat()/3,  // 1/3
    endY = sizeImage.height.toFloat()
)

Box(){
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.banner),
        contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
        sizeImage = it.size
    })
    Box(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize().background(gradient))
}
```

Original:

[image]

After:

[image]

You can also apply the gradient to the `Image()` using the [**`.drawWithCache`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/DrawCacheModifier) modifier and the [**`onDrawWithContent`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#drawwithcontent) that allows the developer to draw before or after the layout's contents.

```
  Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.conero),
      contentDescription = "",
      modifier = Modifier.drawWithCache {
          val gradient = Brush.verticalGradient(
              colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black),
              startY = size.height/3,
              endY = size.height
          )
          onDrawWithContent {
              drawContent()
              drawRect(gradient,blendMode = BlendMode.Multiply)
          }
      }
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't really work as expected. It just makes the image darker. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Also, I don't understand what the `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, `endY` arguments expect. Why do you have `size.width` for `endY`? Shouldn't it be `size.height`?

Comment: @Ashar7 Correct. it should be `size.height` (my bad, tried the code with a square). The `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, `endY` are the coordinates of the gradient. In the code above they are built by `size = this.size`. You can also use a different `blendMode`

Answer (score 11):

Wow, that one took a couple of hours ;)

You can use `Modifier.background` with a `VerticalGradient`. I used a Column to hold the modifiers and made a calculation to get the images size, but your solution might differ, you could calculate or store the size differently, and put the modifiers somewhere else. I left two TODOs in the code so you can tweak the gradient.

```
@Composable
fun Cover(
    name: String,
    imageRes: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp, 8.dp)
) {
    val density = DensityAmbient.current.density
    val width = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val height = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Box(modifier) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            elevation = 4.dp
        ) {
            Stack {
                Image(
                    imageResource(imageRes),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .gravity(Alignment.Center)
                        .aspectRatio(2f)
                        .onPositioned {
                            width.value = it.size.width / density
                            height.value = it.size.height / density
                        },
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                )
                Column(
                    Modifier.size(width.value.dp, height.value.dp)
                        .background(
                            VerticalGradient(
                                listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black),
                                0f,  // TODO: set start
                                500f,  // TODO: set end
                            )
                        )
                ) {}
                Text(
                    text = name,
                    modifier = Modifier.gravity(Alignment.BottomStart)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    style = typography.h6,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my sample looks like:
[image: sample of card with image background, black to transparent gradient and text]

Comment: Looks great! But why did you use `500f`?

Comment: I tried a couple of values and noticed it is going to be different from case to case, so I just left 500 which would look good in the sample. I believe both the number values and the color will change depending on the size and kind of image is going to be there

Answer (score 6):

You can try this approach as well

```
Image(
  painterResource(R.drawable.something),
  null,
  Modifier
  .drawWithCache {
    onDrawWithContent {
      drawContent()
      drawRect(Brush.verticalGradient(
        0.5f to Color.White.copy(alpha=0F), 
        1F to Color.White
      ))
    }
  },
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Straight forward:

```
        Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) {
        Box {
            Image(...)
            Text(
                text = "title",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Brush.verticalGradient(0F to Color.Transparent, .5F to Color.Red, 1F to Color.Red))
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp, top = 16.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here is the answer I was looking for. Succinct. Thank you @AndreClassen :)