# How to convert Dp to pixels in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Most of Jetpack Compose API uses [Dp](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Dp) as a dimensions unit, but sometimes a pixel value is required. How can I convert a dp value to px? Just for an example there's [graphicsLayer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#graphicslayer) modifier that accepts `translationX/Y` arguments in pixels.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

There're [`toPx()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density#topx) and [`roundToPx()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density#roundtopx) methods defined by [Density](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density) interface, you can use it like this:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity

val pxValue = with(LocalDensity.current) { 16.dp.toPx() }

// or

val pxValue = LocalDensity.current.run { 16.dp.toPx() }
```

Such an expression might look confusing if you're new to Kotlin language so let's break it down and see how it works. `toPx()` is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) of [`Dp`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Dp) class, you can think of it as a `Dp` class method. But since `toPx()` is defined inside [Density](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density) interface, you cannot use it unless you provide a density as a [receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45875491/4858777). And at last you can get the current density from an [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal) named [LocalDensity](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#localdensity).

Comment: Is AmbientDensity going to be called CompositionLocalDensity? (Actually, it's called `LocalDensity` now, I checked)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks! Indeed, `Ambient`s are named `CompositionLocal`s since `alpha-12`, I've updated the answer

Comment: great explanation of the syntax; i came here looking for precisely what sorcery that was!

Comment: And if you want to convert from pixels to Dp, it's ```LocalDensity.current.run { 16.toDp() }```

Comment: weird, it requires @Composable context for transforming dp to px. Why?

Comment: What should I do in case of creating custom MeasurePolicy outside of @Composable context ?

Answer (score 44):

@Valeriy's answer is definitely the correct way to do it but if you want it slightly less verbose or you have a lot of converting to do you can create extension functions:

```
@Composable
fun Dp.dpToPx() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@dpToPx.toPx() }


@Composable
fun Int.pxToDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@pxToDp.toDp() }
```

This lets you convert your dp straight to px and vice versa.

```
val dpValue = 16.dp
val pxConverted = dpValue.dpToPx()

val pxValue = 100
val dpConverted = pxValue.pxToDp()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach and there are two advantages:

1. "inline"
2. it is variable (not function)

```
inline val Int.dp: Dp
    @Composable get() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@dp.toDp() }

inline val Dp.px: Float
    @Composable get() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@px.toPx() }
```