# How can I convert a `with` code to a full code in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921799/how-to-convert-dp-to-pixels-in-android-jetpack-compose).

It' wrapped with `with`, I hope to convert it to a full code, how can I do?

BTW, Code B is wrong.

**Code A**

```
val pxValue = with(LocalDensity.current) { 16.dp.toPx() }
```

**Code B**

```
val s = LocalDensity.current
val pxValue=s.16.dp.toPx()
```

**Add Content:**

For example, the Code C is using `with,`  I can write a full Code D instead of Code C without `with`.

**Code C**

```
data class Person(var name: String, var tutorial : String)
var person = Person("Anupam", "Kotlin")

with(person) {
    name = "No Name"
    tutorial = "Kotlin tutorials"
}
```

**Code D**

```
data class Person(var name: String, var tutorial : String)
var person = Person("Anupam", "Kotlin")

person.name = "No Name"
person.tutorial = "Kotlin tutorials"
```

Comment: You can't use `toPx()` without `with()` or something similar. You would have to use more classic ways to convert it, without using Kotlin extensions (I'm not familiar with Android to say what it is).

Comment: Do you mean sth like: `val px = LocalDensity.current.apply { this.16.dp.toPx() }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can you rewrite Code C into Code D, but not Code A into Code B? The difference, as the answer your linked also mentioned, is that `toPx` in Code A is an *extension* method of `Dp` declared in [`Density`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density). It is declared like this:

```
open fun Dp.toPx(): Float
```

On the other hand, none of the properties you use in the `with` block in Code C are extension properties declared in `Person`.

So to call `toPx`, not only do you need an instance of `Density` as the *dispatch receiver*, you also need an instance of `Dp` as the *extension receiver*. (See [this](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/programmer-dictionary-extension-receiver-vs-dispatch-receiver-cd154e57e277) for more info about dispatch vs extension receivers)

With scope functions that change what the implicit receiver `this` means (e.g. `with`/`run`), you can easily provide both of these receivers:

```
with(LocalDensity.current) {  // LocalDensity.current: (implicit) dispatch receiver
    16.dp.toPx() // 16.dp: explicit extension receiver
}
```

It is possible (but not very intuitive or convenient) to provide both receivers without using scope functions. For example, and for academic purposes only, you can declare additional extension functions on `Density`:

```
fun Density.dpToPx(x: Int) = x.dp.toPx()
fun Density.dpToPx(x: Float) = x.dp.toPx()
fun Density.dpToPx(x: Double) = x.dp.toPx()
```

Here the dispatch receiver of `x.dp.toPx` is the same as the extension receiver of the newly declared `Density.toPx`, and the extension receiver is `x.dp`.

Then you can call this like this:

```
LocalDensity.current.dpToPx(16)
```

I strongly recommend you to use `with` when writing real code.

Comment: I read this question and answer with great interest and was thinking, how could this be done without Kotlin 1.7's new Context Receiver feature? TIL. Thanks.

Comment: @k314159 I don't know too much about that feature, but from what I have heard it is used to provide implicit receivers, and it even makes it possible to provide *multiple* ones (?), so it definitely sounds like this feature can be used to do this. Feel free to write another answer showing another way! :)

Comment: @Sweeper I believe even with context receivers feature, the standard way is still to use `with` or other scoping function. I don't understand why OP would like to avoid it.

Comment: @broot Yes, of course. I did not mean to imply otherwise. I was just also interested in how the new feature could be used. I think OP was just trying to understand what's going here (probably confused by the two receivers), and they thought rewriting it without `with` was a good idea to do that.